# Optimal comparison-based stable sorting in constant space

Tags: ds.algorithms, sorting

For a comparison based sorting algorithm, it is desirable to:

1. Be stable
2. Run in $O(n\ \log n)$
3. Operate in $O(1)$ space

I can find algorithms that satisfy any two of these but I can't find any that satisfy all three. Does it exist? Is it proven not to exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mergesort satisfies all three requirements (when merging is performed in place).
See Pardo, L.T., "Stable  sorting  and  merging  with  optimal  space  and  time 
bounds", SIAM J. Comput. 6 (1977), 351-372.

Comment: I think that the algorithm uses $O(1)$ pointers, but has a recursive call stack that is logarithmic in the size of the list. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Mergesort can be implemented without recursion, essentially by doing a bottom-up level-order traversal of the recursion tree.

Comment: there is a nice paper by Salowe and Steiger that describes some background and gives simplified algorithms: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0196-6774(87)90050-2

Comment: Here is an implementation of such a sort, along with a lot of documentation of how it's implemented: https://github.com/BonzaiThePenguin/WikiSort/tree/master